# Selecting an option using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I am having trouble selecting the current filter I applied to the `<select>` tag.
The code is working populating the Combobox. My only concern is, I can't find a way to select a certain option that I selected after the page loads.
As you can see in the second image, the filter works, but the selected option is still **'Select Wallet'** when it should be **'Paymaya'**.
Any ideas on how to properly apply the *"selected"* attribute to the `<option>` tag based on what I clicked.

I hope I explained it well.
I'm a beginner. Sorry for the messy code.

Here's my code populating the select tag:

```
<select name="filter_wallet" id="filter">
      <option value="0">Select Wallet</option>
      <?php
         // Fetching wallets into combobox
         $sql2 = "SELECT wallet_id, wallet_name FROM wallets";
         $wallet = $con->query($sql2) or die($con->connect_error);
         $resultWallet = $wallet->num_rows;

         if($resultWallet > 0){
           while($row2 = $wallet->fetch_assoc()){
         ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row2['wallet_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row2['wallet_name']; ?></option>
     <?php }} ?>
```

Here is my code after submitting the filter button:

```
$wallet_id = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submitFilter'])){
    $wallet_id = $_POST['filter_wallet'];
    if($wallet_id == 0){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_transactions ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_transactions WHERE wallet_id='$wallet_id' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
    }
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_transactions ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
}
$transactions = $con->query($sql) or die($con->connect_error);
$resultTransaction = $transactions->num_rows;
```

ALL RESULT

[image]

FILTERED RESULT

[image]

Comment: DRY! `$wallet_id = 0; $sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_transactions ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
if(isset($_POST['submitFilter'])){
    $wallet_id = $_POST['filter_wallet'];
    if($wallet_id != 0){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_transactions WHERE wallet_id='$wallet_id' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
    }
}
$transactions = $con->query($sql) or die($con->connect_error);
$resultTransaction = $transactions->num_rows;`

Comment: When you loop through to display the wallet options, you need to compare each id with the `wallet_id` that you selected, and add `selected="selected"` to the matching option tag.

Comment: @droopsnoot thanks, this explains the logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like

```
<select name="filter_wallet" id="filter">
      <option value="0">Select Wallet</option>
      <?php
         $filter = isset($_POST['filter_wallet']) ? $_POST['filter_wallet'] : "";  
         // Fetching wallets into combobox
         $sql2 = "SELECT wallet_id, wallet_name FROM wallets";
         $wallet = $con->query($sql2);
         $resultWallet = $wallet->num_rows;

         if($resultWallet > 0){
           while($row2 = $wallet->fetch_assoc()){
           if ($row2['wallet_id'] == $filter)
               $sel = " selected";
           else
               $sel = "";
         ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row2['wallet_id']; ?>" <?php echo $sel; ?>><?php echo $row2['wallet_name']; ?></option>
     <?php }} ?>
```

Presuming that your wallet_id can never be null. Use something else invalid if it can be.